# How to rectify the error rltm is not defined?

Tags: angularjs, pubnub

I am creating a chat application.I am getting the error rltm is not defined even I have defined the rltm file path in my script tag.How can i overcome that?

Comment: May be the path is not loaded. One can only make assumptions without seeing any code. Please share some snippet.